# MouseEvent.movementX returns incorrect value when the pointer is quickly moved inside the browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mouseevent

I've been developing a feature that is based on mouse movement and it uses [`movementX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX) to function. It works great, but I noticed that from time to time, it has strange behavior. When I dug deeper into it, I found out what appears to be an issue with the `movementX` property.

MDN [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementX):

> The movementX read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides
>   the difference in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between the
>   given event and the previous mousemove event. In other words, the
>   value of the property is computed like this:
>   `currentEvent.movementX = currentEvent.screenX - previousEvent.screenX`.

But that's not always the case. If you quickly move the pointer from outside the browser, inside, the value may be equal to or even greater than `screenX` for some reason. Since I can't reproduce this in JSFiddle, I used this simple document and opened it in Chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
      console.log('movementX:', event.movementX, 'clientX:', event.clientX, 'innerWidth:', window.innerWidth)
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's an image describing the problem:

[image: movementX problem]

As you can see, the `movementX` value spikes to `914`. According to the MDN description of the property, it should return the difference between the current `screenX` value, `849`, and the previous one, which is also `849`. Instead of the property being equal to `0`, it is `914` instead.

**Why does that happen?**

Browser: Chrome, Version 72.0.3626.109 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Haven't tested but just a guess, mouse/pointer entering/leaving the client area may be what's causing this issue because move and enter/leave events fire out of sync.  So if tracking the previous position and a window enter event fires, then offset the previous position by the enter position and that would seem to resolve the specific problem.  I do not know the spec in this regard but if movement is spec'd explicitly to allow enter/leave to arbitrarily change the position then no, but otherwise it would indeed be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a bug in Chrome. I've reported it [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=934658#c2).